# Unable to Import Video-Component in JSX

Tags: reactjs, npm, jsx

I am building a TV-Screen with local informations, a video-player and newsticker as a web-application for a friend of mine  who is a doctor. It's for the waiting room.

I have the main-app and wanted to create 2 components which should be imported in the main-app. I am working with nginx and npm. Any time i try to import the video.jsx component like:

```
import { Video } from './Video';
```

I get an "403 Forbidden" error on my localhost-page.

> make: *** Keine Regel vorhanden, um das Ziel „_build/tmp/wztv/Video“,
>     benötigt von „_build/tmp/wztv/main.js“, zu erstellen.  Schluss.

in english for the non-germans^^:

> make: *** No rules to build the target „_build/tmp/wztv/Video“,
>     is needed from „_build/tmp/wztv/main.js“, .  End

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Video } from './Video';

    // Main
    class Main extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          praxisname: 'Praxis Dr. Lurch',
          currenttime: {},
          patientendata: {},
          content: {}
          };
         }

    chooseVideo(newVideo) {
        this.setState({
          src: VIDEOS[newVideo]
        });


      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Video Player</h1>
            <Menu chooseVideo={this.chooseVideo} />
            <Video src={this.state.src} />
          </div>
```

---

video component:

```
    import React from 'react';

    export class Video extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
             <video src={this.props.src}controls autostart autoPlay muted />
          </div>
        );
       }
      }
```

---

menu component (for functionality):

```
    import React from 'react';

    export class Menu extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }
      handleClick(e)  {
        var text = e.target.value;
        this.props.chooseVideo(text);
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <form onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <input type="radio" name="src" value="vid1" /> vid1
            <input type="radio" name="src" value="vid2" /> vid2
            <input type="radio" name="src" value="vid3" /> vid3
            <input type="radio" name="src" value="vid4" /> vid4
          </form>
         );
        }
      }
```

I just want the video to be shown and rendered right.

Comment: Maybe i need to say that I am a complete newbie who started programming 2 months ago. Thank you for the support

Comment: How are you building your React components? That appears to be a critical piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @JimG. I am not sure what exactly you mean but I am building them with a Makefile. "NPM install -> make clean-> make "in the terminal. I hope thats what you needed to know.